# Prove that R and P(R) does not have the same cardinality.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

How can I show such a thing in an elegant, valid way? I know it shouldn't be hard. Well it does have to be plausible and mathematically logic, but I guess I am not expected to rediscover the great, massive proof founded by Cantor. If I am to use what he says, what's the point then? I mean, how can I prove this elegantly as an "Introduction to Set Theory" mere student? I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: What are $R$ and $P(R)$?

Comment: Cantor's proof of this statement is considered to be one of the most elegant proofs in mathematics. Why don't you just use [his proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument)?

Comment: @Rory: The diagonal argument, as given, fits $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb R$. Sure, it can be transformed $\Bbb R$ and $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$. But that's essentially proving Cantor's theorem, not the diagonal argument (which is an instance of the theorem).

Comment: I hope that the experience in this question have taught you not to accept the first answer (or even the second) as soon as they show up. Wait a little bit, and see what others might write. In any case, remember to upvote useful answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea of the proof of Cantor's Theorem is, I think, accessible even to you.  Here it is:

> We say two sets $A$ and $B$ **have the same cardinality** if there is at least one bijection $f : A \to B$.  That is, $f$ has to be a one-to-one and onto map from $A$ to $B$.

So, to prove any set $R$ and its powerset, $\mathcal{P}(R)$, do not have the same cardinality, we just need to prove that there is no bijection between $R$ and $\mathcal{P}(R)$.  But since bijections are **one-to-one** and **onto**, one of these conditions must fail for every map from $R$ to $\mathcal{P}(R)$ (otherwise, if there is some map that exhibits both of these, that would be a bijection).

But the map $h : R  \to \mathcal{P}(R)$ sending $a \in R$ to $\{a \} \in \mathcal{P}(R)$ is an injection...

So that means an injection exists, and maybe more than one does.  And some of those injections might also be surjections...in which case, we would have a bijection between $R$ and $\mathcal{P}(R)$.  So how can we check that all of these injections aren't surjections?  Well, Cantor had the idea that *no* map from $R$ to $\mathcal{P}(R)$, whether injective or not, is surjective, and that's what will be shown below.

---

Okay, so let $f : R \to \mathcal{P}(R)$ be any map.  We want to prove $f$ *cannot* be surjective.  That means we should be able to find an element $z \in \mathcal{P}(R)$ such that there is no $a \in R$ with $f(a) = z$.

Hmm...maybe we can construct this element $z$.  What does the map $f$ do on a basic level?  It sends an element in $R$ to an element in $\mathcal{P}(R)$, i.e., an element in $R$ to a **subset** of $R$.

Okay, well, maybe we can observe where each element in $R$ is being sent to under $f$...and maybe we can include that element in the set we are constructing *if* it isn't already in the subset it is being mapped to, but if it *is* in the subset it is being mapped to, we can leave it out.  That way, the subset we are constructing will be different from every subset being hit by $f$...

That is, let $z = \{ a \in R \mid a \not \in f(a) \}$.  In English, this says: let $z$ be the set of elements in $R$ that are *not* in the subset of $R$ that they are mapped to.  In some sense, we are constructing $z$  by looking at each element of $R$, and making sure $z$ is **different** from the subset each element is mapped to.  Clearly, $z$ is a subset of $R$, and since $z$ is not equal to $f(a)$ for each $a \in R$ (by construction!), then $z \not \in f(R) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(R)$.  But that means we found a subset of $R$ that is not hit under $f$, so $f$ is not surjective.  (Another way to see this is: if $g : A \to B$ is surjective, then $g(A) = B$.  But we just showed $f(R) \neq \mathcal{P}(R)$ since $z \in \mathcal{P}(R)$ but $z \not \in f(R)$.)

Since $f$ was any arbitrary map, we can conclude there is no surjection from $R$ to $\mathcal{P}(R)$, so their cardinalities are different

Comment: Beautifully explained! Thank you :)

Comment: @Meitar You're welcome!

Comment: What if, suppose, every element is being mapped to a subset not containing it? I need some explanation about it...

Comment: I am so dumb lol 
That's a contradiction. I get it. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Meitar You're not dumb, I'm glad you get it!  If every element is being mapped to a subset not containing it, then $z$ would be the set $R$ itself.  No element would be sent to $R$ because every element is in $R$, and elements would not be sent to sets that contain them.

Comment: It as paradoxical as his diagonal XD 
I guess that was his method.

Comment: @Meitar I just want to be clear that there is no contradiction or paradox occurring if you consider a map $f$ that sends each element to a subset that doesn't contain that element.  It is a perfectly reasonable example that you brought up, and the $z$ would then be the entire set/domain $R$.  That is, $R$ would be the element of $\mathcal{P}(R)$ with no element in $R$ being mapped to it under $f$.  I hope that is clear!

Comment: I know what you're saying... It's just that in my proof I assumed that my function is a surjection...

Comment: @Meitar Oh, ok, so you were proving this by contradiction.  That makes sense.

Comment: A minor nitpick, "to prove there is no bijection ... we need to prove there is no surjection ... since ... there is an injection" gives the impression that the existence of an injection and a surjection obviously implies that there is a bijection.

Comment: @ronno Yeah, I understand what you are saying.  I would hope that any person studying this material would already have a firm grasp of bijections to understand what I meant, but I guess we should aim to make our content as accessible as we can.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Due to unsubstantiated, stealth downvotes I have recently received, I have decided to opt out of the reputation accumulation dynamics. When I accumulate a few extra above maintaining minimal functionality, I happily give bounties to answers that have been most helpful to me. This is a good one.

Comment: @Andrew I'm glad this answer has been helpful, and thank you for letting me know! :)  Regarding downvotes, as difficult as it may be, try to remember that downvotes are generally meaningless.  When you are on your death bed one day thinking about your life, one of the least important things you could ever think about at that time is the random downvote of some probably unqualified stranger.  Someone truly qualified to judge whether your content deserves a downvote would also know well enough to leave a comment explaining why.  Best wishes to you!

Comment: Thanks for your sound advice. I have to wait till tomorrow before the system will allow me to o-fficially award it. Best personal regards,

Comment: Hi - Maybe I could return with a follow-up. How do you know you can find such an $a$ where $a\notin f(a)$? Doesn't that already assume $f$ is not surjective. Also when you say "already" it sounds as if there is some recursion to determine if that $a$ is in our out, but if it's out based on previous $f(..)$'s it could still be hit subsequently. Sorry to trouble you further. Thanks.

Comment: @Andrew Sorry for my late reply! I'd be happy to answer your questions.  As far as your first question, remember that we are letting $f$ be **any** map from $R$ to $\mathcal{P}(R)$.  So $f$ is arbitrary.  It's possible that for one map, all of the $a$ are in $f(a)$.  In which case, we *can't* find $a$ such that $a \not \in f(a)$.  In this case, the element of $\mathcal{P}(R)$ not being hit by anything from $R$ would be the empty set $\emptyset$.  Why?  Suppose for some $a \in R$, $f(a) = \emptyset$.  We just said with this map, $a \in f(a)$, which would mean $a \in \emptyset$, a contradiction.

Comment: @Andrew So, in this special case, if for each $a$, $a \in f(a)$, then $\emptyset$ is our element in $\mathcal{P}(R)$ which is not being hit by anything in $R$.  Also, I'm not sure where I used "already' in my answer.  Can you be more specific to which part you are referring to for your second question?

Comment: Thanks for the above. The "already" is in the second line of the paragraph beginning "Okay."

Comment: @Andrew Let's go over how we are constructing this set more carefully.  Remember that our goal is to construct a set which is not hit by any $a$ under the map $f :  R \to mathcal{P}(R)$.  Ok, well, intuitively, let's start looking at elements in $R$ (although, in reality, we can't necessarily do this iteratively because $R$ may be uncountable).  Let's look at some $a_{1} \in \Bbb R$.  $f(a_{1})$ is then a subset of $\Bbb R$.  We want to make our set different from $f(a_{1})$ (otherwise, if it equaled $f(a_{1})$, then the set we are constructing will be hit by $a_{1}$, which we don't want).

Comment: @Andrew Ok, well either $a_{1}$ is in this subset $f(a_{1})$, or it isn't.  If it is, let's NOT include it in our set that we are building.  If it *isn't* in $f(a_{1})$, let's include it.  It doesn't matter that $a_{1}$ may appear as an element in some future subset $f(a_{n})$.  At that time, we will be deciding whether to include or exclude $a_{n}$ from the set we are building.  This will have nothing to do with $a_{1}$, and $a_{1}$ cannot enter the set we are building at any other step than possibly $1$.  So, it is irrelevant if $a_{1}$ is in a future set.  Even if it is, that doesn't...

Comment: @Andrew ...mean we will include it in our set.  With that said, let's do this again.  So we start with an element $a_{1}$.  Let's pretend $a_{1} \not \in f(a_{1})$.  Then the set we are building is now $\{a_{1}\}$.  This is different from $f(a_{1})$ since one of them contains $a_{1}$ and the other doesnt.  Now let's go to the next element in $R$, called $a_{2}$.  After observation, we find that $a_{2} \in f(a_{2})$.  So the set we are building won't include $a_{2}$ to ensure it is different from $f(a_{2})$.  So the set we are building remains as $\{a_{1}\}$, and this is different from...

Comment: @Andrew ...$f(a_{2})$ since one contains $a_{2}$ and the other doesn't.  Now let's move on to the next element in $R$, call it $a_{3}$, and inspect.  We observe that $a_{3}$ is NOT in $f(a_{3})$, so we DO want it in our set we are creating to ensure this set is different from $f(a_{3})$.  So our set is now $\{a_{1}, a_{3}\}$.  This set is different from $f(a_{3})$ because one contains $a_{3}$ and the other doesn't contain $a_{3}$.  Note that at step 3, whether $a_{2}$ was in $f(a_{3})$ was irrelevant.  There is no way for $a_{2}$ to enter our set at any other time than step 2.

Comment: @Andrew At step $n$, all we are deciding is whether to include or exclude $a_{n}$.  Nothing about $a_{k}$ if $k \neq n$.  Our set at step 3, $\{a_{1}, a_{3}\}$ is STILL different from $f(a_{1})$ (why?), and it's STILL different from $f(a_{2})$ (why?). This despite the fact that it's quite possible $a_{1}$ and $a_{2}$ are in $f(a_{3})$.  Whether they are or aren't is irrelevant to the construction of our set at step $3$.  Now, the above is just intuition (and it certainly holds rigorously if $R$ is countable).  If $R$ is uncountable, we can't start with $a_{1}$, move to $a_{2}$, etc.

Comment: @Andrew Rather, in the uncountable setting (and actually in every setting), it's enough to simply define our subset as $Y := \{a \mid a \not \in f(a)\}$.  For any $b \in \Bbb R$, we can argue $f(b) \neq Y$.  Why?  Well, is $b \in f(b)$?  If so, then we know $b \not \in Y$ (by definition of $Y$), showing that $f(b) \neq Y$ (since $b$ is in one and not the other).  Is $b \not \in f(b)$?  If so, we know $b \in Y$ (by definition), showing $f(b) \neq Y$ (since $b$ is in one and not the other).  So in every case, we've shown $Y$ is different from $f(a)$ for each $a$...

Comment: @Andrew ...proving the arbitrary map $f$ is not surjective.  I hope this helps.  Please read this string of comments multiple times if you feel a little confused.  The more you read it, the more you'll understand the bigger picture.  And once you do understand the big picture, you'll understand the main idea of the proof completely.  Feel free to ask any more questions you have.

Comment: Thanks for your most generous, detailed, patient explanation. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can show that any map $f : R \to P(R)$ is not onto as follows: for each $r \in R$, $f(r)$ is a subset of $R$. Thus either $r \in f(r)$ or not. Define $$E = \{r \in R : r \notin f(r) \}.$$
Can you show that $E = f(e)$ for some $e \in R$ leads to a contradiction?

Comment: Thank you all for answering. I know I can show that There can be infinite number of elements in P(R) that are not in R, but it still doesn't prove that |P(R)| does not equal |R|, for example, |P(R)|=n|R|=|R|... :<

Comment: Oh I understand what you are saying! I will try to go this way :)

Comment: Thank you as well. This is practically a good explanation of Cantor's proof. :)

Answer (score 0):

Show that there is no bijective function between a set $X$ and $P(X)$ by contradictions. You just need the definition of bijective and then conclude that there cannot exists such a function. Then this follows as a lemma.

Answer (score 0):

If $R$ = $∅$, $℘$($R$) = { {$∅$} }. Suppose that $R$ ≠ ∅. Then, there is a one-to-one mapping  $ƒ$, $R$ onto ℘($R$). We now consider the set of elements of $R$ which are not mapped to the subset of R under $ƒ$. Let $B$ = {$r$ $∈$ $R$ ; $r$ $∉$ $ƒ$($r$)}. We will try to arrive at some contradiction. Suppose $x$ $∈$ $B$. $⇒$ $x$ $∈$ {$r$ $∈$ $R$ ; $r$ $∉$ $ƒ$($r$)} $⇒$ $x$ $∉$ $ƒ$($x$) $=$ $B$. Next, suppose $x$ $∉$ $B$. Then $x$ $∉$ $ƒ$($x$) and so $x$ $∈$ {$r$ $∈$ $R$ ; $r$ $∉$ $ƒ$($r$)} $=$ $B$, a contradiction.