# Proof: There is no bijection from $P(S)\to S$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm reading Foldes': *Fundamental Structures of Algebra and Discrete Mathematics.* Here:

> [image]
>
> [image]

He proves that there is not bijection from  $P(S)\to S$. The problem is that I'm unable to understand this proof. I'd like to know some heuristic to understand it, but notice that I want to understand this proof and not some alternative proof of it *I know there are alternative proofs to this, but being unable to understand this one makes my brain itch*. Can you help me?

Comment: Which part of the proof don't you understand?

Comment: Check out my explanation of the proof here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084940/prove-that-r-and-pr-does-not-have-the-same-cardinality

Comment: The idea of the proof is simple enough. Assume there _is_ a bijection $g$ that takes a subset to an element. Then construct a subset $F\subseteq S$ such that the element $g(F) \in S$  is both an element of $F$ and an element of the complement of $F$. Claim a contradiction has occurred, and therefore no bijection can exist. Personally, I prefer the proof that there is no surjection from $S$ to $\mathcal P(S)$, but that's just me.

Comment: @Wojowu When he created $F$. There are too many propositions and it confuses me.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is indeed difficult to read! The reason for this may be, that since it is a proof by contradiction, it starts contradicting itself semantically in a confusing way where you can loose track of what is being assumed.

Here is how I would try to break it down:

- The set $F$ contains the images of all sets $A$ mapped under $g$ to an element outside of themselves.
- If $F$ is mapped by $g$ to an element outside of itself, $F$ is like $A$ above and so its image should be in $F$. Contradiction.
- On the other hand, if $F$ is mapped via $g$ to an element $x$ from itself, it is NOT like $A$ above.
- Maybe $x$ could still be an element of $F$? It would be possible, had $x$ been the image of some other set $A$ satisfying the requirements. But injectivity implies $F$ to be the only set mapping to this particular $x$. Thus $x$ cannot be an element of $F$. Again we have a contradiction.

I find this particular proof to be particularly hard to follow - even when I tried to break it down myself. Let me know if it helped you in any way.

---

In accordance with Arthur's comment, I too prefer the proof that there is no surjection from $S$ to $\mathcal P(S)$. In particular, I like the following rendering of it that I came up with which mimics Cantor's Diagonal Argument in a more direct way:

Suppose $f:S\to\mathcal P(S)$ is a surjection. Note that an indicator function for a subset $A\subseteq S$ is a function $\mathbf 1_A:S\to\{0,1\}$ defined by
$$
\mathbf 1_A(x)=
\begin{cases}
1&\text{if }x\in A\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

It suffices to show that we can point to an indicator function $\mathbf 1_A:S\to\{0,1\}$ which is NOT of the form $\mathbf 1_{f(x)}$. Then $A\in\mathcal P(S)$ is NOT one of the sets $f(x)$ and so $f$ cannot be surjective. Define
$$
\mathbf 1_A(x):=1-\mathbf 1_{f(x)}(x)
$$
Note that this is well defined and outputs either $0$ or $1$, so it must be an indicator function. And it differs from each of the indicator functions $\mathbf 1_{f(x)}$ in at least one value. It follows that $f$ is NOT surjective.

---

The way this mimics Cantor's Diagonal Argument is, that if we take $S=\mathbb N$, the map $n\mapsto\mathbf 1_{f(n)}$ maps a natural number to an infinite sequence of $0$'s and $1$'s corresponding to an infinite binary expansion of a number in the interval $[0,1]$, and $\mathbf 1_A$ then yields a binary expansion of a number that differs in the $n$-th place from the binary expansion spelled out by $\mathbf 1_{f(n)}$.